# vscode cmake move from visual studio 17 to 19

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have been using vscode with the cmake integration for visual studio community edition 2017. I'm only using visual studio integration to vscode, not the IDE.  I just moved to Vstudio 19.  Now cmake is failing because I cannot get it to recognize that it should use the new visual studio. See error output below.

What is really interesting is that it's using the correct cmake.exe from the VS19 folder, but the parameter it uses is "-G "Visual Studio 15 2017" that is causing the problem.  I removed the c_cpp_properties.json file (then CMake: Clean/Rebuild) in my .vscode folder which had a reference to VS17 and that didn't help.

I've tried to remove all the extensions (C/C++ Extension Pack), checked every folder/file in my projects for references to that VS 17. Removed the build folder and CMake: Clean/Rebuild after reinstalling the extensions..

```
[variant] Loaded new set of variants
[kit] Successfully loaded 4 kits from C:\Users\wood\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json
[main] Configuring folder: mycode 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -Hc:/Users/wood/mycode/build -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -T host=x64 -A win32
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -Hc:/Users/wood/mycode -Bc:/Users/wood/OneDrive/mycode/build -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -T host=x64 -A win32
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (project):
[cmake]   Generator
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Visual Studio 15 2017
[cmake] 
[cmake]   could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Users/wood/OneDrive/mycode/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Any ideas where else that -G setting might be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked for 24 hours, posted a question, then solved in in the first five minutes.

I removed the file.
C:\Users\wood\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json

Well, just renamed it.

Uninstalled the C/C++ extension pack, then re-installed the extension pack. It looked like there was a command to rescan for visual studio, but I missed that as it went by. When rebuilding the cmake I was asked to pick the architecture and everything is working again.

That rescan of visual studio, re-created the cmake-tools-kits.json file with the correct references.

Comment: Yes adding extension settings out of visual studio code settings was a bas joke from cmake tools developers.